# Custom posts in different columns style

Tags: php, posts, customization

I'm trying to output a custom type posts with a sticky/featured work in a col-8 (thumbnail) and col-4 (content) then the rests of the posts should be in col-4. So far I have tried the code below but that only output all the posts, sure if I repeat the code and contain the output in col-4 its achievable but I don't think that's the best practice of doing it.

```
<?php
        $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'recentproject', 'orderby' => 'rand', 'posts_per_page' => '1') );

        ?>
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-8 columns">
            <?php edit_post_link(); // Always handy to have Edit Post Links available ?>
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if thumbnail exists ?>
                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4 columns">
            <h4 class="project_title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php echo the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <?php
        $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'recentproject', 'orderby' => 'rand', 'posts_per_page' => '3') );
        ?>
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="col-4 columns">
                <h4 class="project_title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                <?php edit_post_link(); // Always handy to have Edit Post Links available ?>
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if thumbnail exists ?>
                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
```

To explain what I intend to do see the image below.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [offset](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) paramater in WP_Query e.g.

```
<?php
        $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'recentproject', 'orderby' => 'rand', 'posts_per_page' => '1') );
        $counter=0;
        ?>
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); $counter++; ?>
        <div class="col-8 columns">
            <?php edit_post_link(); // Always handy to have Edit Post Links available ?>
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if thumbnail exists ?>
                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4 columns">
            <h4 class="project_title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php echo the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <?php
        $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'recentproject', 'orderby' => 'rand', 'posts_per_page' => '3', 'offset' => '1' ) );
        ?>
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="col-4 columns">
                <h4 class="project_title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                <?php edit_post_link(); // Always handy to have Edit Post Links available ?>
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if thumbnail exists ?>
                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
```

Basically it ignores the first xx posts in the query, so you would use offset => 1 if you want to ignore the first post in your query

I don't think it will work with "rand" order though, is the rand a necessity?
**Edit: Using count & 1 query**

```
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'recentproject', 'orderby' => 'rand', 'posts_per_page' => '4') );
$count = 1;
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
 if($count == '1') { ?>
  <div class="col-8 columns">
   <?php edit_post_link(); // Always handy to have Edit Post Links available ?>
   <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if thumbnail exists ?>
    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>   
   <?php endif; ?>
  </div>

  <div class="col-4 columns">
   <h4 class="project_title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
    <?php echo the_content(); ?>
  </div>
 <?php } else { ?>

  <div class="col-4 columns">
   <h4 class="project_title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
   <?php edit_post_link(); // Always handy to have Edit Post Links available ?>
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if thumbnail exists ?>
     <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php echo the_content(); ?>
   </div>

  <?php
  }
 $count++;
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Not tested but should work, basically it counts the posts and changes the HTML code depending on the count number

Comment: Yeah rand is needed, so it will show different projects when the page is refreshed. Forgot remove counter as I don't think its needed there. What did you mean ignores the first post? did you mean so it won't duplicate whatever is in the large column and output it in the 3 columns?

Comment: Yes that's what offset does, it ignores the first post from the query e.g. first query displays the first post, the second query skips the post from the first query.

I am going to add another answer which will work with rand

Comment: Oh right, yeah so far its not ignoring the first post. Is there a way of doing this without repeating the wp_query?

Comment: You can using a counter, check if count is equal to 1 and do xx code and do yy if not 1, will add code to my answer

Comment: Oh right I did try using counter but I guess I was doing it wrong, though the answer you posted works but it breaks the 3 columns, it doesn't align horizontally but vertically instead. I tried wrapping it around a row and change the counter number but no luck.

Comment: It will be a missing div somewhere that's causing it, you have a URL I can take a peek at to find the error?

Comment: I'm currently developing it on my localhost though. But here is the whole code, http://pastebin.com/zRWjsZWz

Comment: Nvm I think I have fixed it. I moved the else statement and the rest of the bottom php under <div class="row">.

Comment: Cool, glad you got it sorted, if you can mark my answer it would be appreciated (arrow to the left of my answer)

Comment: Hi, going to reopen this thread. I wonder how could you do an statement like if there's only 2 posts it wraps in <div class="large-6"> then if there's 3 posts then it wraps in large-4.